# What's the equivalent of OpenDialog for a C#/Monogame app for Mac?

Tags: c#, .net, macos, monogame

I've started to learn C# and Monogame a few weeks ago, and the project I'm working on to learn to use the framework is a simple game with a map made of arrays. Now that I have this working, I want to know what's the equivalent of OpenDialog but for macOS, as I'm coding a in-game map editor for my game (a very simple one) and I want to be able to open/write/load a JSON file where the data of the maps will be, on runtime.

If I was a windows user, I could have used OpenDialog but because I can't I'm wondering what to do. Is there a C# library of some kind that could help me? I would really like to not mix different languages (like using Swift and NSOpenPanel for example) because it's a pain and also because the only language I already know is Lua...

Thanks for helping! :)

Answer (score 0):

Monogame does not have this functionality built in.  Most games use a save slot feature instead of direct filesystem selection.

Map editors are usually done using winforms applications external to the game itself.

To do this task in Monogame, use `File` class and others in the `System.IO` namespace to Read and Write files to the filesystem. You must have write access to the folder.  You will have to write your own user interface.

Depending on the state of Winforms implementation on Mac, you may be able to add a form to your game and use the FileDialog class directly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I believe winform is not available on macOS, so I won't be able to create a winform application for the map editor of my game. I could however use my girlfriend's computer (windows) to code the winform application but I'm wondering if once it's coded, I'll be able to at least use the winform app on my macOS, or if even that is impossible on a Mac device?